# Detect a plugin in IE browser - javascript?

Tags: javascript, ie-plugins

Is it possible to detect whether my ActiveX plugin is installed or not in IE browser through javascript?

Any pointers would be quite helpful.

Update: In GChrome browser I can find the number of plugins installed by running `navigator.plugins.length` in javascript.. Is there any similar code available for IE?

Answer (score 0):

```
function AXOrNull(progId) {
  try {
    return new ActiveXObject(progId);
  }
  catch (ex) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.

The code that you'd mentioned will initialize the plugin. However I want to find out if my plugin is installed or not without initialzing it (using new).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hmm maybe `typeof(ActiveXObject) != 'undefined'`?